# Else If android not working

Tags: android, if-statement

I want the output to be green if the counter is 20 or above and red if it is below 20. this is the code I have so far and it isnt working.

```
  add1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = counter += 1;
            if (counter >= 20) {
                display.setText(Color.GREEN);
                //display.setText("" + counter);
            }
            else if (counter < 20) {
                display.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                //display.setText("" + counter);
            }
            display.setText("" + counter);
        }
    });
    sub1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = counter -= 1;
            if (counter >= 20) {
                display.setText(Color.GREEN);
                //display.setText("" + counter);
            }
            else if (counter < 20){
                display.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                //display.setText("" + counter);
            }
            display.setText("" + counter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you mean: `display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);` instead of `display.setText(Color.GREEN);`?

Comment: poor if/else construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

- use `counter += 1` instead of `counter = counter += 1`. Same for subtraction.
- avoid duplicating code
- use `setTextColor()` instead of `setText()`.

---

```
add1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter += 1;
        updateDisplay();
    }
});

sub1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter -= 1;
        updateDisplay();
    }
});
```

And have this method somewhere:

```
void updateDisplay () {
   display.setTextColor(counter < 20 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
   display.setText("" + counter);
}
```

Comment: Well put, I missed the counter issue on my first read through.

Comment: @Peter - I missed it as well at first.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your time and input. I am very very new at this and trying to teach myself through several tutorials without abusing others knowledge on these kind of forums. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the color of the textview called display you need to switch:

```
display.setText(Color.GREEN);
```

to

```
display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Also you can probably make your `else if` just an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

As mentioned in the comments, you are trying to set the text to `Color.GREEN` which is a constant integer representing the green color, while you should be doing like you did in the RED case

```
display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

On a different matter, You shouldn't be using `else if` in that statement.

Since your first `if` asks, is my counter 20 or more, change color to green, and if it's under, change to red.

You only have 2 cases which overlaps the entire "spectrum" of your variable if you will.

You should use `if` and `else` in that case

```
        counter = counter += 1;
        if (counter >= 20) {
            display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            //display.setText("" + counter);
        }
        else { // not 20 or above, meaning < 20
            display.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //display.setText("" + counter);
        }
        display.setText("" + counter);
```

`else if` would be useful if you had more cases, for example

```
        counter = counter += 1;
        if (counter >= 20) {
            display.setText(Color.GREEN);
            //display.setText("" + counter);
        }
        else if (counter < 20 && counter >= 10) { // counter is between 10 and 20, not including 20
            display.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //display.setText("" + counter);
        }
        else { // under 10, not including 10
             display.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //display.setText("" + counter);
        display.setText("" + counter);
```

It might be good practice to try and always have an `else` statement to check for an illegal value (especially if it's an input from the user). even only for a sanity check, or error handling and printing.